# Java script doesn't run inside the html file in ionic frame

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a form which is used to get users input. I want a JS to run in the header to check the validation.

my html code:

```
<ion-view view-title="{{chat.name}}">
  <ion-content class="padding">

         <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


    <script>
        function validateForm(objForm) {

        if (objForm.Make.selectedIndex == 0) {
        alert("Please select a request");
        returnStatus = 0;
        };

        var x = document.forms["request"]["description"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please fill out the description");
        return false;
        }
    }

</script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Service Request</h2>
<br></br>
    <div id="container">

        <form action="" method="post" id="customtheme" name ="request">
            <p>
                <label for="RequestType" style="padding-right:56px">Request Type:</label>

                    <SELECT NAME="Make" id="request">
                        <option value="0">--Please select--</option>
                        <option value="1">Car Pass Ticket</option>

                    </SELECT>   

            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="description" style="padding-right:56px" style="vertical-align: top;">Description:</label>
                <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="10" rows="6" required></textarea>
            </p>

            <p>
                <input TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Submit" name="submit" style="align:center" id="submitbutton" onClick="validateForm(document.request)"/>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I have a java script in the header but that doesn't get executed. what can be done to fix the error or any other way I can do validation.

Comment: Put your validation logic in an AngulaJS controller, not in a free-floating script tag.

Comment: Try wrapping your script in the $(document).ready() function.

Comment: @Ondrej This is not a jQuery application

Comment: @Gajotres, ah, ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put that in a controller. Why do you have it there?

The `<ion-view>` is injected into `<ion-nav-view>` which is basically sugar over ui-router's `<ui-view>`.

Why do you have head, body etc inside ion-view?

Go through angular docs and then Ionic docs. This jQuery approach wont work. And remove that jq-ui.css. You already have Ionic, which is a UI framework.